# Make specific rules for string PHP

Tags: php

I would like to sanitize the string input of users. I would like to prevent special characters and code symbols such as `<`, `>`, `&` etc but allow `space` and `single quotes (')`. What I have done so far is:

```
$query = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', '', htmlentities($request->search_name, ENT_COMPAT));
```

When I test it using the above code, it also removes spaces, which I need. Any help is highly appreciated.

**EDIT:**

If I type

```
mark O'neal"<>!
```

My code above prints it wrongly:

```
markOnealquotltgt
```

it should output:

```
mark O'nealquotltgt
```

Comment: Don't do that.  Instead, you need to learn how to properly encode text.

Comment: show us your input and expect output

Comment: I added my output expectations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to add the space and `'` characters to your character set:

```
$search_name = "mark O'neal\"<>!";
echo preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9\- ']/", '', htmlentities($search_name, ENT_COMPAT));
```

Output:

```
mark O'nealquotltgt
```

[Demo on 3v4l.org](https://3v4l.org/5iHOo)

Answer (score 1):

Ignore space usging `\s`

```
preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-\s]/', ... );
```

Comment: What is that plus doing there? You want to ignore pluses too?

Comment: Yes will that ignore plus symbol as well?

Comment: It will, if you do want to ignore the `+` symbol you can use `\s+`.